# I'm stuck trying to export multiple Landsat (5 and 7) images from Google Earth Engine at once

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, landsat

I loaded multiple images from Landsat 5 and Landsat 7 onto my Google Earth engine, from 1988 until 2022 for my region of interest. I'm trying to export these images individually to Google Drive as GeoTIFF files. I'm a little stuck on how to do so. Here is my code:

```
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
            .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
            .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};

var l5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
              .filterDate('1984-01-01', '2011-12-31') 
              .map(cloudMaskL457)
              .filterBounds(aoi)
              .map(function(a){
                return a.set('year', ee.Image(a).date().get('year'))
              })

var l7 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
              .filterDate('2012-01-01', '2022-12-31')
              .map(cloudMaskL457)
              .filterBounds(aoi)
              .map(function(a){
                return a.set('year', ee.Image(a).date().get('year'))
              })

var list = ee.List([])

for(var a=1984; a < 2023; a++) {

if(a < 2012) {

var fill5 = l5.filterMetadata('year', 'equals', a).median()
var l5final = fill5.set('year', a)
                   .set('product', 'l5')
                   
list=list.add(l5final)

} else { 

var fill7 = l7.filterMetadata('year', 'equals', a).median()
var l7final = fill7.set('year', a)
                   .set('product', 'l7')

list=list.add(l7final)
}


print(list)

var finalCol = ee.ImageCollection(list).map(function(a) {
            return a.set('bands', ee.Image(a).bandNames().length())
          })
          .filterMetadata('bands','equals', 11) 
          
print(finalCol)

for(var a = 1988; a < 2023; a++) {
Map.addLayer(finalCol.filterMetadata('year', 'equals', a), imageVisParam, 'Year'+' '+a, false)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export the image collection using [Rodrigo Principe's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/23470/rodrigo-e-principe) batch module grom `geetools`:

```
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(finalCol, 'collection output', {
  scale: 30,
  region: aoi
});
```

Although trying to export the whole collection would take more memory than available, so try to export by year ranges