# Download Sentinel-2A imagery to local machine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to GEE. I have been trying to filter the Sentinel-2A image collection based on an uploaded vector area and download individual scenes instead of mosaics. During this process, I encountered an issue. When I exported a single scene to my cloud storage, it appeared as four scenes with a TIFF file size of less than 10 MB. However, when I downloaded it to my local machine and opened it with ArcGIS, the band values were shown as unknown. How Can I modify my code to handle this

```
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection("users/xxx66/test");

//cloud move
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
 
  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
 
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
 
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}
 
// select
var s2_collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .filterDate('2023-05-01', '2023-09-01')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 5))
                  .select(['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B9', 'B11', 'B12','QA60'])
                  .map(function(image){
                      return image.clip(roi)
                  })
                  .map(maskS2clouds);
             
print("s2_collection",s2_collection)
     
var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};
 
Map.addLayer(s2_collection, rgbVis, 's2_collection');
Map.centerObject(roi,7)
 
//Display vector boundary
var styling = {color:"red",fillColor:"00000000"};
Map.addLayer(roi.style(styling),{},"boundary");
 
//Image set export method
function exportImageCollection(imgCol) {
  var indexList = imgCol.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(), ["system:index"])
                        .get("list");
  indexList.evaluate(function(indexs) {
    for (var i=0; i<indexs.length; i++) {
      var image = imgCol.filter(ee.Filter.eq("system:index", indexs[i])).first();
      image = image.toInt16();
      Export.image.toDrive({
        image: image,
        description: indexs[i],
        fileNamePrefix: indexs[i],
        folder: 'S2_images',
        region: roi,
        scale: 10,
        crs: "EPSG:4326",
        maxPixels: 1e13
      });
    }
  });
}
exportImageCollection(s2_collection);
```

Comment: "When I exported a single scene to my cloud storage" is not what you show here. As a new user, I recommend you to read [Client vs Server](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server). If you want to export the entire collection, check [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/463286/im-stuck-trying-to-export-multiple-landsat-5-and-7-images-from-google-earth-e/463420#463420). Four scenes by date from S2-A? Yes, it could be 4 different grid zones. If you don't mosaic by date that would happen (I don't recommend using mosaic function in GEE, takes all resources)

Comment: Sorry, this is my wrong expression, should be exported to Google  Drive.What I want to ask is why arcgis opens the display band value unknown after exporting

Comment: This could be because you have user-side functions (for loop) when exporting. That could make your code fail. If ArcGIS shows a band value unknown, it's because the exporting process failed

Comment: Thank you very much. I know what I should do next